# Add folder to asset pipeline path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

We have a rails app that I recently updated from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2. This app services multiple clients. To customize it for each client, we have the directory `app/themes`. In there are submodules. Each submodule contains things like `locales/en.yml`, `views/layouts`, `views/controller_name`, etc. We use the `prepend_view_path` to add the theme views, and the `I18n.load_path` to add in the locales. We're looking at using the asset pipeline so we can keep all the mix of client material out of the public directory, and keep it contained in each theme.

Is there a way i can dynamically tell rails to load which theme/theme-name/assets folder i want? We use settings logic to set which theme is active. So if i have the theme set to "google", the `ApplicationController` then loads files from the path:

```
app/themes/google/locales/*.yml
app/themes/google/views
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have the manifest file,

```
app/themes/google/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

easily accessible to the layout, much like you would in an `app/views/layouts` file:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application"
```

Is there a way i can do this? or do we need to manually move the assets into the actual assets directory?

Comment: There is a way to load assets per controller , but that is not what you're looking for . You may consider , that asset-pipeline (in production) precompiles and optimizes all the assets in a single file (respectively `application.js` and `application.css`) in  `/public` .The purpose is to decrease calls to the server to fetch assets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Was able to do it in the application.rb:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/settings.rb"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/themes/#{Settings.theme}/assets/stylesheets"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/themes/#{Settings.theme}/assets/images"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/themes/#{Settings.theme}/assets/javascripts"
```

Comment: after adding a line like `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"`, or the ones you added, is there a command that needs to be run?  The fonts I'm trying to use are not working.  Figured this was a similar enough question to add a comment here rather than start a new question.

Comment: Is their a reason why you're adding fonts in the asset pipeline? Can still put them in public and reference them that way, like any other public file you would in 3.0 prior.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to merge zurb foundation icons into my project, and there are four font files of different types and .css stylesheets that, so far, I have assumed just get placed in the foundation.css file I already have from using zurb foundation.

Comment: You'd also need to restart your application to access the new paths after adding this line.

Comment: Even though you have a subdirectory we only need its file name in view: `link_to -, asset_path(filename)`