# how to have assets other than js and css files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I have some [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) which I want to have them in my JS codes I put them under `app/assets/3d-models` and when I try to get a link to it I use:

```
<%= asset_path("3d-models/splits2/xxx.obj") %>
```

But the output is `/3d-models/splits2/xxx.obj` which obviously the `404 NOT FOUND` is the result(i.e the asset not found, the wrong link!)

#### Question:

How can I get an access link to a file other than common files used in rails' assets?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different assets. Just place them into assets folder and link to them correctly.

Rails are using **assets pipeline**. This is a concept, which provides a better way to serve some static files to a website. In Rails it is implemented by **Sprockets gem**. Please read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

You can also have other static files directly in **public folder** and link to those files anywhere from your app. This will not be included in assets pipeline.

If you use **assets_path** helper method, then there is a fingerprint added to a file so the URL to the file is different then.

Please check [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your answer does not provide me a solid solution, I already have read the rails asset pipeline article but I couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: @dariush Try to add app/assets/3d-models folder to assets path. [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735635/add-folder-to-asset-pipeline-path) or [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

Then assets pipeline should be enabled also for your app/assets/3d-models folder. You can then link to any file from that folder with <%= asset_path("3d-models/splits2/xxx.obj") %>

Comment: I have in my project:
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths <<  Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'inspinia')